# ASP.NET Core WebAPI - StatusCode 404 NotFound from web app

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have some trouble with ASP.NET Core web API. I created a very basic web API and I try to call it from a ASP.NET Core web application (very basic too). When I call the web API, I get this response :

```
{StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  X-XSS-Protection: 1
  Connection: close
  Pragma: no-cache
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 3631
}}  System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage
```

My colleague run exactly the same .NET solution on his computer, and he succees in calling the web API :

```
{StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Date: Fri, 01 Sep 2023 12:06:44 GMT
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
}, Trailing Headers:
{
}}
```

Do you have any ideas of what's wrong with my computer ?

Thanks

Check all configuration is correct.
Test code on an other computer => it works correctly

Comment: How we can help you if you don't provide us with any useful information? So, try to change the code at line 7

Comment: We can't get any useful information from your question, It's difficult to find the solution just based on these information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand your remark, but I clearly don't know what additional information can be useful... It is sure that the code is correct. What type of info you need ? Environment variables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:
I had to define environment variables to correctly use conda (for Python). I add HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY variables. That's the root cause of the issue. If I remove its, the C# code runs normally.